# How to integrate SLF4J logging with Spring 4?

Tags: maven, logging, slf4j, log4j2, spring-4

Couldn't find any good answer why slf4j logging not working with spring 4. Thanks to [this post](https://springframework.guru/using-log4j-2-spring-boot/) I've made particularly all work, but the author didn't mention that:

> The mandatory logging dependency in Spring is the Jakarta Commons Logging API (JCL)

(http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/).

It means that if we want slf4j to work **WE MUST EXCLUDE** **commons-logging** from our classpath (or pom.xml if using maven). While using maven spring-core automatically picks commons-logging. (I understood this when executed the command "mvn dependency:tree").

STEPS TO REPRODUCE:

1. Exclude commons-logging from spring-core

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
       <version>${spring.version}</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
               <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add to the pom.xml next dependencies:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.19</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
       <version>2.5</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.5</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.5</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.19</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Create log4j2.xml file like this (if you want log4j2 logging through slf4j).

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Configuration status="WARN">
   <Appenders>
   <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
       <PatternLayout
           pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
   </Console>
   </Appenders>
   <Loggers>
   <Root level="error">
       <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
   </Root>
   <logger level="info" additivity="false" name="org.springframework.security">
       <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
   </logger>
   <logger level="info" additivity="false" name="org.springframework.web">
       <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
   </logger>
   <logger level="warn" additivity="false" name="controllers">
       <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
   </logger>
   </Loggers>
   </Configuration>
   ```
4. write log messages in your classes:

   ```
   private final Logger logger =LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
   logger.debug("This is a debug message");
   logger.info("This is an info message");
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to exclude commons-logging.  If you use log4j-jcl instead of jcl-over-slf4j the Spring logging will be routed to log4j directly instead of going through slf4j.

Answer (score 1):

Now, thanx to @rgoers my logging part of pom.xml looks like:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.19</version>
    </dependency>     
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. You may want to upgrade to 2.6.1, to get the benefits of garbage-free or low garbage logging.

Comment: Also, if Ralph's answer helped solve the problem, consider accepting his answer so he gets the reputation points.